# Can't reach stats for Portuguese language SE in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

I type Portuguese into the Switch Sites box and all I get is Politics, Poker, SO in Portuguese, and relevant metas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portuguese Language only hit public beta this week and SEDE doesn't update till the weekend.

I *think* new sites should be added automatically? Ping me if it doesn't appear by this time next week.

Comment: Thanks a lot, did not pay enough attention to the age column.